# Coupon not getting applied?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, promotions, backoffice

I have created promotion through backoffice but coupon is not getting applied on percentage discount for products. Its showing something like coupon code entered is no longer valid. I have attached image also. Any suggestion?
[image]

Comment: is the coupon a SingleCodeCoupon? Is it active? Does it have any date restrictions on it? There a a few more details needed in order for a proper diagnosis :)

Answer (score 3):

I advise you to check that you performed all steps in the hybris instruction: [Creating Single-Code Coupon](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/d7b5fed2ce89401aae4d3a2bfddfd1ea.html)

In short, coupon creation is not enough. You need to:

- Setup promotion rule to use that coupon
- Publish promotion rule
- Verify that coupon status is active